# c++ functions using boost::geometry deliver wrong results when compiled with -O2 flag

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, g++, compiler-optimization

I wrote a c++ class to perform some polygon operations (calculate the minimum distance and intersection area of two polygons). I compile it with `g++ 8.3.0`. Everything works perfectly when compiled without the `-O2` compiler flag. When I use the `-O2` flag, I get wrong results in some cases (for example, the intersection area of two equal squares with a side length of `1.0` and the bottom left corner located at the origin is `-2.0` instead of the expected result `1.0`.)

I read in another stackoverflow post that this is most likely because there is a memory leak or another bug in my code and very unlikely that this is a compiler bug. Is there such a bug in my code?

What I tried:

- I double checked with the documentation of `boost` that I am using all functions and classes correctly.
- I used `cppcheck` on my code (no results).
- I used `clang --analyze` on my code (no results).

Is there something I missed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>

#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/area.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/assign.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

//#include "ndarray.h"

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

// use the following two commands to compile:
//
//WARNING: DO NOT USE O2. IT DESTROYS bg::correct FUNCTIONALITY
// g++ -lboost_system -c -fPIC polygoncalc.cpp -o polygoncalc.o -O2
// g++ -lboost_system -shared -Wl,-soname,libpolygoncalc.so -o libpolygoncalc.so polygoncalc.o -O2

typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
//typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point_type;
typedef bg::model::polygon<point_type> polygon_type;

//typedef std::vector< std::vector<double>> Matrix;

class PolygonCalc{

    public:
        const double helloworld(){
//            std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
            return 0.123;
        }

        double test_calc(){

//            Point points[] = {Point(0,0), Point(1,0), Point(1,1), Point(0,1)};
//            Point points2[] = {Point(0.5,0.5), Point(1.5,0.5), Point(1.5, 1.5), Point(0.5,1.5)};

            polygon_type poly1 {{{0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 1.0}}};
            polygon_type poly2 {{{5.5, 0.5}, {6.5, 0.5}, {6.5, 1.5}, {5.5, 1.5}}};

//            polygon_type poly1 {{{0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}}};
//            polygon_type poly2 {{{0.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1.5}}};

            bg::correct(poly1);
            bg::correct(poly2);

//            std::vector<point_type> points1;
//            std::vector<point_type> points2;
//
//            points1.push_back(point_type(0.0,0.0));
//            points1.push_back(point_type(1.0, 0.0));
//            points1.push_back(point_type(1.0, 1.0));
//            points1.push_back(point_type(0.0, 1.0));
//
//            points2.push_back(point_type(0.5, 0.5));
//            points2.push_back(point_type(1.5, 0.5));
//            points2.push_back(point_type(1.5, 1.5));
//            points2.push_back(point_type(0.5, 1.5));

//            boost::geometry::read_wkt(
//                "POLYGON((2 1.3,2.4 1.7,2.8 1.8,3.4 1.2,3.7 1.6,3.4 2,4.1 3,5.3 2.6,5.4 1.2,4.9 0.8,2.9 0.7,2 1.3)"
//                    "(4.0 2.0, 4.2 1.4, 4.8 1.9, 4.4 2.2, 4.0 2.0))", poly1);
//
//            boost::geometry::read_wkt(
//                "POLYGON((4.0 -0.5 , 3.5 1.0 , 2.0 1.5 , 3.5 2.0 , 4.0 3.5 , 4.5 2.0 , 6.0 1.5 , 4.5 1.0 , 4.0 -0.5))", poly2);

//            polygon_type poly1;
//            polygon_type poly2;
//
//            bg::assign_points(poly1, points1);
//            bg::assign_points(poly2, points2);

            std::deque<polygon_type> output;
            bg::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);

//            std::cout << bg::area(poly1) <<std::endl;
//            std::cout << bg::area(poly2) <<std::endl;


            double totalArea = 0.0;

            int i = 0;
            BOOST_FOREACH(polygon_type const& p, output)
            {

//                std::cout << i++ << ": " << boost::geometry::area(p) << std::endl;

                totalArea += bg::area(p);
            }

            double d = bg::distance(poly1, poly2);

            std::cout << d << std::endl;

            return totalArea;

        }

        int test_nparray(double *A, int n){

//        int M, N;
//
//        M = poly1.size();
//        N = poly1[0].size();
//
//        std::cout << M << std::endl << N << std::endl;

            int i;
            double sum = 0.0;

            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {

                sum += A[i];

            }

            std::cout << "n: " << n << std::endl;

            std::cout << sum / n << std::endl;

            return n;

        }

        double min_poly_distance(double *poly1x, double *poly1y, double *poly2x, double *poly2y, int m, int n){

            int i;

            std::vector<point_type> points1;
            std::vector<point_type> points2;

            for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
                points1.push_back(point_type(poly1x[i], poly1y[i]));
//                std::cout << poly1x[i] << " " << poly1y[i] << std::endl;
            }

            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                points2.push_back(point_type(poly2x[i], poly2y[i]));
            }

            polygon_type poly1;
            polygon_type poly2;

            bg::assign_points(poly1, points1);
            bg::assign_points(poly2, points2);

            bg::correct(poly1);
            bg::correct(poly2);

            std::deque<polygon_type> output;
            bg::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);

            double totalArea = 0.0;

            BOOST_FOREACH(polygon_type const& p, output)
            {
                totalArea += bg::area(p);
            }

            if (totalArea > 0.0){
                return 0.0;
            }

            return bg::distance(poly1, poly2);

        }

        double poly_intersection_area(double *poly1x, double *poly1y, double *poly2x, double *poly2y, int m, int n){

            int i;

            std::vector<point_type> points1;
            std::vector<point_type> points2;

            for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
                points1.push_back(point_type(poly1x[i], poly1y[i]));
//                std::cout << poly1x[i] << " " << poly1y[i] << std::endl;
            }

            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                points2.push_back(point_type(poly2x[i], poly2y[i]));
            }

            polygon_type poly1;
            polygon_type poly2;

            bg::assign_points(poly1, points1);
            bg::assign_points(poly2, points2);

            bg::correct(poly1);
            bg::correct(poly2);

            std::deque<polygon_type> output;
            bg::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);

            double totalArea = 0.0;

            BOOST_FOREACH(polygon_type const& p, output)
            {
                totalArea += bg::area(p);
            }

            return totalArea;

        }

        double poly_intersection_area_ratio(double *poly1x, double *poly1y, double *poly2x, double *poly2y, int m, int n){

            int i;

            std::vector<point_type> points1;
            std::vector<point_type> points2;

            for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
                points1.push_back(point_type(poly1x[i], poly1y[i]));
//                std::cout << poly1x[i] << " " << poly1y[i] << std::endl;
            }

            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                points2.push_back(point_type(poly2x[i], poly2y[i]));
            }

            polygon_type poly1;
            polygon_type poly2;

            bg::assign_points(poly1, points1);
            bg::assign_points(poly2, points2);

            bg::correct(poly1);
            bg::correct(poly2);

            std::deque<polygon_type> output;
            bg::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);

            double totalArea = 0.0;

            BOOST_FOREACH(polygon_type const& p, output)
            {
                totalArea += bg::area(p);
            }

            double area1 = bg::area(poly1);
            double area2 = bg::area(poly2);

            if (area1 > area2) {

                return totalArea / area2;

            } else {

                return totalArea / area1;

            }

            return totalArea;

        }

};


extern "C" {
    PolygonCalc* PolygonCalc_new(){ return new PolygonCalc; }
    const double PolygonCalc_helloworld(PolygonCalc* polygoncalc){ return polygoncalc->helloworld(); }
    double PolygonCalc_test_calc(PolygonCalc* polygoncalc){ return polygoncalc->test_calc(); }
    int PolygonCalc_test_nparray(double *A, int n, PolygonCalc* polygoncalc){ return polygoncalc->test_nparray(A, n); }
    double PolygonCalc_min_poly_distance(double *poly1x, double *poly1y, double *poly2x, double *poly2y, int m, int n, PolygonCalc* polygoncalc){

        return polygoncalc->min_poly_distance(poly1x, poly1y, poly2x, poly2y, m, n);

    }
    double PolygonCalc_poly_intersection_area(double *poly1x, double *poly1y, double *poly2x, double *poly2y, int m, int n, PolygonCalc* polygoncalc){

        return polygoncalc->poly_intersection_area(poly1x, poly1y, poly2x, poly2y, m, n);

    }
    double PolygonCalc_poly_intersection_area_ratio(double *poly1x, double *poly1y, double *poly2x, double *poly2y, int m, int n, PolygonCalc* polygoncalc){

        return polygoncalc->poly_intersection_area_ratio(poly1x, poly1y, poly2x, poly2y, m, n);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The solution was to make the `PolygonCalc *polygoncalc` the first argument instead of the last (for all functions in section `extern "C"`) and supply the object explicitly when calling the function from python. In another stackoverflow post, the author didn't state that the object must be supplied as an argument, and it does seem to work without optimization by coincidence in most cases. I did some more research, it looks like the `-foptimize-sibling-calls` flag is the culprit.